# Problem understanding some BSRR assignment operations

Tags: stm32, c

I'm learning about the STM32F405/415 in my course and having some trouble understanding some applications of the BSRR. Specifically how it's used in this function:

```
void HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIO_TypeDef* GPIOx, uint16_t GPIO_Pin, GPIO_PinState PinState)
{
  if(PinState != GPIO_PIN_RESET)
  {
    GPIOx->BSRR = GPIO_Pin;
  }
  else
  {
    GPIOx->BSRR = (uint32_t)GPIO_Pin << 16U;
  }
}
```

The function is part of the HAL driver. It's called by this code in particular:

```
while (1)
{
  JoyState = HAL_GPIO_ReadPin (JOY_C_GPIO_Port, JOY_C_Pin);
  HAL_GPIO_WritePin (LD6_GPIO_Port, LD6_Pin, JoyState);
}
```

The effect of the code is that the LED toggles on and off with the press of the left direction on the onboard joystick (JOY_C_GPIO_Port and Joy_C_Pin) but I can't really tell why it works.

My understanding of the code is that this section below is assigning the location of the pin to its own port and that this is somehow turning it off:

```
if(PinState != GPIO_PIN_RESET)
  {
    GPIOx->BSRR = GPIO_Pin;
  }
```

And my understanding of this part below is that the pin location is being assigned to "16U" of the port that the pin belongs to, and if the pin is not set it now will be. But I don't know what 16U is (16th register? documentation says 1-15? "U"?)

Can anyone explain this?

Comment: What is wrong? I can see that it read the button state with `HAL_GPIO_ReadPin` and set the LED pin accordingly.

Comment: "16U" means 16 unsigned. I suggest you do research about C basics :) Useful keywords: Struct, pointer, bit shift.

Answer (score 1):

BSRR is 32-bit register. Low 16 bits are the SET function, high 16 bits are the RESET function. IO pin defines are 16-bit bitmasks. Therefore to reset bits you write the mask to 16 higher bits.